# How to remove \u0000 from string?

Tags: javascript

I am encoding PDU message. At beggining of message I got String Some thing like :

```
\u0005\u0000\f0)@\u0000This is testing\u0000
```

How to remove it (`\u0005`...) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Regular Expression to remove unicode char from the string :

```
 /*\\u([0-9]|[a-fA-F])([0-9]|[a-fA-F])([0-9]|[a-fA-F])([0-9]|[a-fA-F])/
```

Comment: Working solution...though * is not required. in the end, 'g' global scope will work fine

`.replace(/\\u([0-9]|[a-fA-F])([0-9]|[a-fA-F])([0-9]|[a-fA-F])([0-9]|[a-fA-F])/g, "")`