# Javascript: Extra character in concatenated string preventing match with object key

Tags: javascript, regex, string, object, concatenation

I'm trying to access an object within another object using an object key. I'm concatenating the values of a group of  `<select>` elements to build a string that matches the key. Unfortunately this never works. Here's the code below:

```
    var valueKeyString = "";
    $(".keySelector").each(function(){
        valueKeyString += $(this).val();
    });
    if (geoAttrs[selectedGeoAttr].rowCol == "row") {
        mapData = rowValueGroups[valueKeyString];
    } else if (geoAttrs[selectedGeoAttr].rowCol == "col") {
        mapData = colValueGroups[valueKeyString];
    }
```

After trying a good number of things I tested the strings character by character using `charCodeAt()`:

```
    var test1 = valueKeyString;
    for (var i = 0, len = valueKeyString.length; i < len; i++) {
      test1 += valueKeyString.charCodeAt(i)+" ";
    }
    if (geoAttrs[selectedGeoAttr].rowCol == "row") {
        Object.keys(colValueGroups).forEach(function(group) {
            var test2 = group;
            for (var i = 0, len = group.length; i < len; i++) {
              test2 += group.charCodeAt(i)+" ";
            }
            console.log(test1);
            console.log(test2)                
        })

        mapData = colValueGroups[valueKeyString];
    }
```

My concatenated strings all had an extra character with a charCode of 0 at the point of concatenation. Couldn't figure out why it was there or how to get rid of it using a regEx or `str.replace()`. Ended up with an ugly but functional solution where I just test the object keys to see if they contain the values from the `<select>` elements:

```
    var valueKeys = [];
    $(".keySelector").each(function(){
        valueKeys.push($(this).val());
    });
    if (geoAttrs[selectedGeoAttr].rowCol == "row") {
        Object.keys(colValueGroups).forEach(function(group) {
            var groupHasAllKeys = true;
                valueKeys.forEach(function(key) {
                    if (group.indexOf(key) == -1 ) {
                        groupHasAllKeys = false;
                    }
                });
            if(groupHasAllKeys) {
                mapData = colValueGroups[group];
            }  
        });
    } else if (geoAttrs[selectedGeoAttr].rowCol == "col") {
        Object.keys(rowValueGroups).forEach(function(group) {
            var groupHasAllKeys = true;
                valueKeys.forEach(function(key) {
                    if (group.indexOf(key) == -1 ) {
                        groupHasAllKeys = false;
                    }
                });
            if(groupHasAllKeys) {
                mapData = rowValueGroups[group];
            }  
        });
    }
```

There's got to be a better way, right? What the hell is going on here?

EDIT: `rowValueGroups` might look something like this:

```
{
  "35_to_44_yearsMale": {
    "4654387684": {
      "value": 215
    },
    "4654387685": {
      "value": 175
    },
    "4654387686": {
      "value": 687
    },
    "4654387687": {
      "value": 172
    }
  },
  "45_to_54_yearsMale": {
    "4654387684": {
      "value": 516
    },
    "4654387685": {
      "value": 223
    },
    "4654387686": {
      "value": 54
    },
    "4654387687": {
      "value": 164
    }
  }
}
```

`valueKeyString` should be `"45_to_54_yearsMale"` or the like.

This is survey data. I'm extracting the `rowValueGroups` data from the output of a nicolaskruchten/pivottable custom renderer. (Specifically from the `pivotData.tree` object if you're curious). I'm not looking to alter the pivottable core to change how those keys are formatted, so I just figured I'd concatenate a couple of values from a select element to make it work.

Here's part of the console output from the tests above:

```
35_to_44_yearsMale51 53 95 116 111 95 52 52 95 121 101 97 114 115 0 77 97 108 101
35_to_44_yearsMale51 53 95 116 111 95 52 52 95 121 101 97 114 115 77 97 108 101
```

First line is the test done on valueKeyString and the second on one of the keys from `rowValueGroups`. Note that the initial string looks identical, (the Firefox console actually outputs a little character-not-found square in between "years" and "Male" for the `valueKeyString` one) but the `charCodeAt()` turns up that weird 0 character at the point of concatenation.

Comment: An example of values would be helpful, for `valueKeyString` and `rowValueGroups`. Would make it easier to get an idea of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Added details in an Edit.

Comment: What if you just cleaned the string after your each? Like `valueKeyString = valueKeyString.replace(/[^a-z0-9_-]+/gi,'')`

Comment: Gave it a try. It doesn't clean out that weird character. It seems like regular expressions and the like don't actually recognize it as a character so they can't get rid of it. Nevertheless it seems enough to keep the strings from matching.

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible demo on jsfiddle? I am particularly interested in the html for the keySelector elements.

Comment: @dave: when you can, let me know if the solutions proposed works for you (if they are not tonreach a working solution can be useful to provide a relevant extract of the source html, as stated by Sheepy). Thank you!

Comment: I'll see if I can't reproduce this on JSfiddle. The keySelector elements are all being created dynamically so I'm not sure if the results will be the same.  This project may be open-sourced at some point which will make it easier for me to share the code publicly, but right now I have to be careful about how much I expose.

Comment: I think @Sheepy raised a good point about the elements with keySelector class. You may have already checked prior posting, but just in case: did you make sure the `null` characters are not already there? (e.g. C uses the null character as the end of string - could be worth outputting the charCodes of each value right away) or if you get undesired elements when calling `$(".keySelector")`? (could be worth checking for their count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `null` characters in your string. This regex will remove them:

```
valueKeyString = valueKeyString.replace( /\0/g, '' )
```

*Reference: [Removing null characters from a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22809513/2892649)*

Answer (score 0):

If you identify the char code you can try to replace it using exactly its code:

```
var valueKeyString = "";
$(".keySelector").each(function(){
    valueKeyString += $(this).val();
});
valueKeyString = valueKeyString.replace(new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(0),"g"),'');
```

Or presuming the string already comes `\0`-terminated directly from the jquery `$(this).val()` you can try another approach:

```
var valueKeyString = "";
$(".keySelector").each(function(){
    s = $(this).val();
    if ( s.charCodeAt(s.length - 1) == 0 )
        s = s.substring(0, s.length - 1);
    valueKeyString += s;
});
```

The above snippet check if the last char of each freshly obtained string from `$(this).val()` is null-terminated (just to be sure) and remove the last char with `substring()`.

Comment: Neither solution will effectively remove the weird 0 character. It's as if it's not a real character, just something else there that returns a char code of 0.   I haven't been able to find any effective way of removing it.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using jQuery you can try `trim()`:

```
var valueKeyString = "";
$(".keySelector").each(function(){
    valueKeyString += $(this).val().trim();
});
```